# Wordpress: Oneengine theme responsive issues

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress

I'm currently having issues with the responsive actions on a site. I'm using the Oneengine theme (very good theme) and the "background" images I'm using aren't responsive when viewed on a device.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to make the images used for the background responsive? Here is the site I’m working on
http://www.jamiebull.co.uk/Meadows_site
When viewed in the chrome emulator for the iPhone 5 the site displays (Aside from the header logo) correctly , however this is not the case when actually being used on the device as it only displays a portion of the image rather than scaling it down. This is the case across mobile and tablet devices.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to solve this please? I’ve tried bits of code and various plugins such as PB Responsive Image, but nothing seems to be affect it.
I've tried the code below in my stylesheet;

```css
img {
     border: 0 none;
     max-width: 100%;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This only affects the images I’m using as backgrounds for the panels and the footer, images I have within the other panels and the footer seem to render correctly when viewed on smaller devices.

I'm still quite new to coding, so anything will help!